# What languages does Zipf's law not hold for?

Tags: statistics, applications

Despite reading on a book of mine that all languages of all times obeyed Zipf's law, the [english Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law) only says *most*. Is it correct? If so, is a counterexample known?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I found the answer to this very question on linguistics.stackexchange, [here.](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6371/are-there-natural-languages-that-do-not-obey-zipfs-law)